# Is there a way to limit access to a directory (like .htpassword) but using PHP logins?

Tags: php, .htaccess, download, password-protection

I have a web folder that I would like to restrict access to via password protection. I would like to have multiple user accounts so .htpassword may not be the answer here. The folder contains web pages and .exe files for download and I would like to ensure someone cannot access an exe file just by knowing the URL.

Is there any way to use PHP to limit access to all contents in a folder or would it be best to just use a PHP page to launch file downloads and never expose the exe's URL?

Thanks

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm pretty sure .htpassword allows for multiple "accounts".

Comment: There are Apache http auth modules for mysql database user account lists. A typical PHP form/session login could be utilized per RewriteCond and REMOTE_ADDR or HTTP_COOKIE session id probing and temporary lock files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to protect a directory with php. You could always create seperate htaccess files in subdirectories and do a require a user but you'd probably be better off just using a php login, in addition a login form and logout looks much more professional.

Answer (score 0):

you can't authenticate straight using php, but you can use a database, here is a example of [htaccess check in databases](http://www.widexl.com/tutorials/htaccess.html#auth_mysql), and that database can be updated by PHP, so you've got esentially the same thing